# Laravel : phpunit cannot open file ExampleTest.php

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, composer-php

Hi i am quit new in Laravel PHPUnit, getting the following error :

```
Laravel : phpunit cannot open file ExampleTest.php
```

I don't have idea why i am getting this error. I installed PHPUnit globally and when i run "phpunit" in terminal it runs fine. But I want to run it on specific file like :

```
phpunit ExampleTest
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are on the project root and referencing the file inside the tests folder.

Example:

```
phpunit tests/ExampleTest.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I am working in Windows. Try to use the full path:

```
C:\Desktop\code\blog\vendor\bin>phpunit C:\Desktop\code\blog\tests\Feature\ExampleTest.php
PHPUnit 7.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
Time: 1.46 seconds, Memory: 10.00MB
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: In my Windows server it also worked with relative path of test .php file from laravel installation

Answer (score 1):

This started happening when I upgrade phpUnit, I had to update phpStorm to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit tests\Unit\ExampleTest.php
```

it will work surly
but first install phpunit globally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you call wrong to your test.
Try like this :

```
php artisan test --filter YourTestClassName
```